# gmaps4rails in ActiveAdmin: render_to_string error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, gmaps4rails

When trying to use render_to_string method in an ActiveAdmin controller:

```
marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/applications/info")
```

I got the following error

```
undefined method `render_to_string' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Show
```

It seems render_to_string is also a method used in ActiveAdmin.
How can I use the one of gmaps4rails ?